# Option to override child's CSS from parent application in angular

Tags: css, angular, sass, themes, angular-library

I have a package/library (cs-clock) written in Angular to generate a UI Widget. This was published to a local repository. This library has some default styles within the library codebase.
Now I have another application where this library is used as an NPM Package via package.json. When the parent is trying to render the widget  - The default styles are rendered from the library.

Now, I want to specify styles from parent to this library which means whenever a new theme CSS file is included in the parent, the child library should be able to render those styles.

I tried with the following options:

1. Using encapsulation property of Angular- By setting it to None and exposing classes
2. Using ::ng-deep, :host /deep/, :host >>>
3. Putting a CSS file in index.html of the parent with !important to the classes specified in it.

Unfortunately, These approaches does not seem to be the ideal one. Is there any other way through which my use-case can be achieved in a better way.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: My first port of call would be to include the stylesheet in the `styles` array in `angular.json`.

Comment: @MikePoole - Thanks. But even if you put in styles array. I have to use !important because of CSS precedence

Comment: yes that is true. I mentioned it because it seems a cleaner approach than importing the script in index.html if for no other reasons than it  speeding up your initial loading screen and managing your styles. If you'd like to create a StackBlitz example I'm happy to take a look at the specific example and suggest how it could be implemented in `styles.scss` without an !important arms race.